# Can I query hbase tables in a namespace using Apache Drill?

Tags: namespaces, hbase, apache-drill

I see the tables in hbase when I say show tables;

```
jdbc:drill:zk=<zkhost>> USE hbase;
+-------+------------------------------------+
|  ok   |              summary               |
+-------+------------------------------------+
| true  | Default schema changed to [hbase]  |
+-------+------------------------------------+

ns is the namespace
table1,2,3 are tables inside the namespace.

: jdbc:drill:zk=<zkhost>> show tables;
+---------------+----------------------------------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA  |            TABLE_NAME            |
+---------------+----------------------------------+
| hbase         | ATLAS_ENTITY_AUDIT_EVENTS        |
| hbase         | ns:table1                        |
| hbase         | ns:table2                        |
| hbase         | ns:table3                        |
| hbase         | atlas_janus                      |
+---------------+----------------------------------+
6 rows selected (30.111 seconds)
```

But when I try to query the table, drill doesnt identify the tables inside the namespace.

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=vginthw496> select * from hbase.table2 limit 10;
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 19: Object 'table2' not found within 'hbase'


[Error Id: 02353729-39b2-4894-a21f-b6662a2a7a3c on <hostname>:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

How do I query hbase tables inside a namespace using apache drill?

Answer (score 0):

using ``` `` ```, like this:

```
select * from `namespace:table` limit 1;
```